# Creating date list from start_date & end_date input

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a range of dates that can be parsed by daily or weekly granularity and have hit a roadblock.  I have a function that allows you to enter a start month,start year, end month, end year, and granularity and returns the date range according to the granularity.

I am able to run this successfully for daily granularity, but when running for weekly granularity, every new month restarts at 1.  Looking at the below example:

```
2015-11-01  2015-11-08  2015-11-15  2015-11-22  2015-11-29  2015-12-01  2015-12-08  2015-12-15  2015-12-22  2015-12-29  2016-01-01  2016-01-08
```

I would like it to appear as:

```
2015-11-01  2015-11-08  2015-11-15  2015-11-22  2015-11-29  2015-12-06  2015-12-13  2015-12-20  2015-12-27  2016-01-03
```

I understand why this is happening - at the end of each for loop the variable "d" is force set to 1.  I tried to add additional if statements after the "dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)"  but I know that is really inefficient coding. I added the snippit of what I tried below:

```
if monthday(m,y) – d < 7 {
   d = monthday(m,y) –d
   if m = 12 {
     m = 1
     y = y+1
   else {
     m = m+1
   }
 }
```

The functions used are copied below.

Any insight into how I could do this would be much appreciated!

```
///  Function to decide how many days in a month
  function monthday (month,year) {
    var months31 = [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
    var months30 = [4,6,9,11]
    var leapyear = [2016,2020,2024,2028,2032]    /// if this code is still being used in 2036 I'll eat my hat

    if (months31.indexOf(month) >=0){
      var result = 31}
    else if (months30.indexOf(month) >=0){
      var result = 30}
    else if (month==2 && leapyear.indexOf(year) >=0){
      var result = 29}
    else if (month==2 && year != 2016){
      var result = 28}

    return result
  }


////Date Range - calculates # of days/weeks between 2 date ranges

  function dateRange (start_month,start_year,end_month,end_year,granularity) {

    var dates = [];
    var d0 = [start_year,start_month];
    var d1 = [end_year,end_month];

    switch (granularity) {
      case "Daily":
        for (var y = d0[0]; y <= d1[0]; y++) {
          if ((y == d0[0]) && (d0[0] != d1[0])) {     // if year=start_year && year != end year   ...  start from start_month and loop up to month 12
            for (var m = d0[1]; m <= 12; m++) {      
              for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d++) {
                dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
              }
            } 
          }
          if ((y != d0[0]) && (y!= d1[0])) {         //  if year != start_year && year != end year ....  start from month 1 to month 12    - this would 2015 data in pulling Dec 2014 - April 2016
            for (var m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {      
              for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d++) {
                dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
              }
            } 
          }
          if ((y != d0[0]) && (y == d1[0])) {       //   if year !=start_year && year = end_year   ....  start from month 1 up until end_month
            for (var m = 1; m <= d1[1]; m++) {      
              for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d++) {
                dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
              }
            } 
          }

          if ((y == d0[0]) && (y == d1[0])) {      /// if year=start_year && year = end_year   ....  start from start_month to end_month
            for (var m = d0[1]; m <= d1[1]; m++) {      
              for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d++) {
                dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
              }
            } 
          }
        }
        break;
      case "Weekly":
        for (var y = d0[0]; y <= d1[0]; y++) {
          if ((y == d0[0]) && (d0[0] != d1[0])) {     // if year=start_year && year != end year   ...  start from start_month and loop up to month 12
            for (var m = d0[1]; m <= 12; m++) {      
              for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d+=7) {
                dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
              }
            } 
          }
          if ((y != d0[0]) && (y!= d1[0])) {         //  if year != start_year && year != end year ....  start from month 1 to month 12    - this would 2015 data in pulling Dec 2014 - April 2016
            for (var m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {      
              for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d+=7) {
                dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
              }
            } 
          }
          if ((y != d0[0]) && (y == d1[0])) {       //   if year !=start_year && year = end_year   ....  start from month 1 up until end_month
            for (var m = 1; m <= d1[1]; m++) {      
              for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d+=7) {
                dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
              }
            } 
          }

          if ((y == d0[0]) && (y == d1[0])) {      /// if year=start_year && year = end_year   ....  start from start_month to end_month
            for (var m = d0[1]; m <= d1[1]; m++) {      
              for (var d =1;d <= monthday(m,y); d+=7) {
                dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)
              }
            } 
          }
        }
       break;
      }
    return dates
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to control the month length, let Date object do it for you.

```
function formatDate(date) {
   return date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) + '-' + ('0' + date.getDate()).substr(-2);
}

function dateRange (start_month,start_year,end_month,end_year,granularity) {
    var date = new Date(start_year + '-' + start_month + '-01');
    var endDate = new Date(end_year + '-' + end_month + '-01');
    var arr = [];

    while(date < endDate) {
        arr.push(formatDate(date));
        switch (granularity) {
            case 'Daily':
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // date++
                break;
            case 'Weekly':
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7); // week++
                break;
            case 'Monthly':
                date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
                break;
            // ...
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Is it something you were looking for?